# acts_as_ferret error in windows7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install acts_as_ferret in windows7.But am getting an error

Using acts-as-taggable-on (2.1.1)

```
Installing jk-ferret (0.11.8.3) with native extensions C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9
.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in bui
ld_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::Ex
tensionBuildError)

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

my gem file contails following gemlist

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.1'
gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'
gem 'contacts', '1.2.4'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'db_populate'
gem 'gravtastic'
gem 'acts_as_ferret'
gem 'packet'
gem 'rmagick','2.9.1'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'will_paginate','3.0.pre2'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.0', :require => 'thinking_sphinx'
#gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git', :branch => 'rails3'
#gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.0.pre', :path => 'vendor/ckeditor-3.4.0.pre'
gem 'ckeditor', '3.5.4', :path => 'vendor/ckeditor-3.5.4'
gem 'mongrel'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'seed-fu'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'ryanb-acts-as-list'
gem 'tzinfo'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'authlogic-oauth'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
gem 'rails-erd'
gem 'crypt', :require => 'crypt/blowfish'
gem "pdfkit", :git => "https://github.com/huerlisi/PDFKit.git"
gem 'ssl_requirement'
```

Can anyone suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. This is perhaps not a direct solution to you problem. But, you sould look elsewhere for searching in rails 3.

From the acts_as_ferret  readme

```
aaf is not yet ready for Rails3. Feel free to submit patches!

Rails 3 :More Like this no longer works for unsaved records (test fails in 
content_test.rb test_more_like_this_new_record)

Rails 3: Sorting does not work - causes failure in sorting test & pagination test.
```

It's also not well maintained. If you do this search "acts_as_ferret windows". You'll see the word "buggy" alot.

So. what to do

**1. make your own simple search**

This is for the model Post.
posts/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def index
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
end
```

models/post.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('title LIKE ? OR text LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%" )
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

**2. Make a full text search**

In a full text search you'll get features like a normal web search engine gives you.
You can do "test + work" and so on.

If you really need full text search, you should check out.

[Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/)

[Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot)

and 
[elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

[Episode 120: Thinking Sphinx (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx-revised)

[Episode 278: Searching with Sunspot](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-searching-with-sunspot)

[Episode 307: ElasticSearch Part 2 (pro)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2)

[Episode 306:Elasticsearch Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1)